# How do you fix wget from comingling download data when running multiple concurrent instances?

Tags: bash, unix, multiprocessing, wget

I am running a script that in turn calls another script multiple times in the background with different sets of parameters.

The secondary script first does a wget on an ftp url to get a listing of files at that url.  It outputs that to a unique filename.

**Simplified example:**
Each of these is being called by a separate instance of the secondary script running in the background.

```
wget --no-verbose 'ftp://foo.com/' -O '/downloads/foo/foo_listing.html' >foo.log

wget --no-verbose 'ftp://bar.com/' -O '/downloads/bar/bar_listing.html' >bar.log
```

When I run the secondary script once at a time, everything behaves as expected.  I get an html file with a list of files, links to them, and information about the files the same way I would when viewing an ftp url through a browser.

**Continued simplified one at a time (and expected) example results:**

**foo_listing.html:**

```
...
<a href="ftp://foo.com/foo1.xml">foo1.xml</a> ...
<a href="ftp://foo.com/foo2.xml">foo2.xml</a> ...
...
```

**bar_listing.html:**

```
...
<a href="ftp://bar.com/bar3.xml">bar3.xml</a> ...
<a href="ftp://bar.com/bar4.xml">bar4.xml</a> ...
...
```

When I run the secondary script many times in the background, some of the resulting files, although they have the base urls correct (the one that was passed in) the files listed are from a different run of wget.

**Continued simplified multiprocessing (and actual) example results:**

**foo_listing.html:**

```
...
<a href="ftp://foo.com/bar3.xml">bar3.xml</a> ...
<a href="ftp://foo.com/bar4.xml">bar4.xml</a> ...
...
```

**bar_listing.html**
correct, as above

Oddly enough, all other files I download seem to work just fine.  It's only these listing files that get jumbled up.

The current workaround is to put in a 5 second delay between backgrounded processes.  With only that one change everything works perfectly.

---

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Please don't recommend using some other method of getting the listing files or not running concurrently.  I'd like to actually know how to fix this when using wget in many backgrounded processes if possible.

**EDIT:**

Note:

I am not referring to the status output that wget spews to the screen.  I don't care at all about that (that is actually also being stored in separate log files and is working correctly).  I'm referring to the data wget is downloading from the web.

Also, I cannot show the exact code that I am using as it is proprietary for my company.  There is nothing "wrong" with my code as it works perfectly when putting in a 5 second delay between backgrounded instances.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the filename generating code right? Does everything work as expected when you're running one `wget` at a time?

Comment: Yep, the current workaround is putting in a 5 second delay.  With only that one change everything works as expected.

Comment: Just in case that wasn't clear.  All the filename generation is happening correctly.  Even if it wasn't that would mean that each line would be correct as it output to the file.  Instead on each line of the file some parts are consistently for one instance of wget and other parts, consistently, are from another instance.

Comment: The examples above are as close as I can give.  As I've said, everything works so long as I put in a delay between putting in processes.  I can't show the exact code as it has proprietary information in it belonging to my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log bug with Gnu, use something else for now whenever possible, put in time delays between concurrent runs.  Possibly create a wrapper for getting ftp directory listings that only allows one at a time to be retrieved.

:-/